# Best Clustering Technique for Probability Scores

Tags: clustering, k-means, hierarchical-clustering, latent-class, model-based-clustering

I have a data which which have 17 variables i.e. 17-Dimension data. The Data is a result of Max-Diff exercise which is performed for ranking these 17 attributes and have comparative preference/importance and probability of choice of each
attribute. So in summary this data is of around 2000 rows and 17 columns values ranging between 0 and 1. Now I want to create meaningful market segments using this data. Just wondering if anyone can help me in deciding best clustering technique for completing this task.

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is both very broad and rather unclear. It would be difficult for anybody to advise on what might be the "best" clustering technique for data they have not seen any part of, nor the structure of, and only the sparsest of details (what does "probability scores resulted from choice experiment" actually mean?) are available. I suggest you have a look at our help page on [how to ask a good question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), which may help you refine it.

Comment: Do you have 1-dimensional data that is bound by 0 & 1? Do any other variables exist that you want to take into account in making the clustering? If people made choices to get a probability, how many choices did they make? Did everyone make the same number of choices? Do you have any reason (from subject matter knowledge) to believe that different clusters exist? If so, how many?

Comment: @Silverfish Probability of choice are probability scores assigned to each attribute for every respondent after Max-Diff Estimation. If you have not anything like this, please follow the link https://www.sawtoothsoftware.com/download/techpap/maxdifftech.pdf and read page number 13. I have also modified my question little bit. Hope Now the data is more clear to everybody.

Comment: @gung Please see modified question of dimension of data. The choice experiment is based on Max-Diff exercise. In this experiment each respondent had made trade off using 15 sets of randomly selected 4 attributes. PoC scores have been generated using hierarchical bayesian estimation of this data. For your question whether clusters exist or not, how you decide this thing? I am asking a bunch of people for their views on some features, there much be some groups of people having same kind of views. As far as number of clusters is concern, this question is very common in any cluster technique.

Comment: As the others noted, due to the broadness of the question, I would begin by evaluating basic things about the data before choosing a specific algorithm. Does the data contain many outliers? is it noisy? are the clusters easily separable? I'd do a 2d scatterplot of the first 2 PCAs or use an algorithm such as [tSNE](https://lvdmaaten.github.io/tsne/) to figure out how to attack it.

Answer (score 1):

If your data are 17-dimensional probability *histograms* (i.e. every row sums up to 1) then you can try the following:

1. Format your data as CSV, 2000 rows, 17 columns (+ a textual label column if you have one)
2. Load the data into ELKI
3. Choose a hierarchy extraction algorithm from the clustering.hierarchical.extraction (or so) package. ''Update'': for example `clustering.hierarchical.extraction.SimplifiedHierarchyExtraction` which is a nice automatic way for cutting the tree without having to choose the height or the number of clusters `k`.
4. Choose Anderberg hierarchical clustering: `AnderbergHierarchicalClustering` because it is faster than `AGNES`.
5. Try complete linkage first and maybe `GroupAverageLinkageMethod`
6. Choose a distance function from the probability package, say chi squared distance `probabilistic.ChiSquaredDistanceFunction` or `probabilistic.SqrtJensenShannonDivergenceDistanceFunction` (these worked well for me on such data)

Then look at the dendrogram, if this exhibits nice clusters. There probably are some outliers, too. I'd focus on the dendrogram, and only treat the automatic extraction (step 3) as a guide. You have several parameters to vary to get a good result. But at the end, you really need to look at the data again, if it is any good for your problem.

Here is an example dendrogram, clusters extracted with above simplified extraction and minimum size 50 objects. The data are color histograms, Chi^2 distance, group average linkage.

[image]

From that plot, I would try again with a larger minimum cluster size.
Let's try sqrt jensen shannon, complete linkage, and min size 100:

[image]

The yellow cluster to the right should probably be cut into two (probably one is less than 100 objects). Some clusters have an outlier that should be dropped. But maybe not too bad for a start.

Too bad you can't "edit" the extracted clusters in the plot. I'm not aware of an easy way to identify e.g. an outlier here easily.

Comment: Although I voted +1, I'd want to call you for a more meaty details. `SimpleSomething`, `SqrtSomething` should be named, for me. Especially, what are the other alternatives to the chi squared distance?  Some guides to choose between them? It is an important choice. Maybe a few words about automatiuc extraction, too. Pardon for cavils...

Comment: I don't have an ELKI on my mobile, so I cannot look them up and check their references. Fire up ELKI, the class names are easy to find. Sqrt is jensen-shannon divergence based IIRC.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Thank you for your response. I was working with my data and just wondering if I can apply the simplest algorithm K-Means Clustering. But as a very basic question in k-means clustering, I am not able to figure out number of k for this. Can anyone suggest anything regarding this technique whether I should use it or not. If yes, how to select k?. PS: I am working in R :)

Comment: @ttnphns today I had access to a desktop PC, and could fire up ELKI. I have added the class names of my suggestion.

Comment: @DileepVishwakarma with the proposed approach (sorry, no R) you don't have to choose `k`.